# How to display unicode data in a file with named entities in different colours in a popup window with scrolled area in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to display a file having Unicode data (Malayalam) in a window with a scrolled area, with all the named entities in different colours in `tkinter` (PYTHON).

For example, consider the sentence - `'Python is a programming language.'`

In my window, Python should be in a different colour. My file contains more than 100 lines. So I need the display in a scrolled area and text in it having different colours.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the text widget. To color certain words or characters you will need to define a tag, and apply that tag to a range of text.